# Logstash udp input not working

Tags: logging, udp, log4net, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am quite new to logstash but I've been spending quite some time in trying to get this right with no success. I am sending my logs from multiple applications on different server via udp to be logged.
Here's the logstash configuration:

```
input{
  udp{
    port => 5960
    type => "log4net"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "(?m)%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sourceTimestamp}\s*%{WORD:System}\s*%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}\s*-\s*%{WORD:logger}\s*-\s*%{NOTSPACE:source}\s*%{NOTSPACE:action}\s*%{UUID:transactionId}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    host => "[mylocalip]"
    port => "9200"
   }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Unfortunately no message is logged. I checked and made sure that the port is available when I start logstash. I also configured properly the firewall to allow udp message via this port. When I tcpdump I can see the udp messages arriving. Additionally I tried another method of input (logs from nginx) and it works ok.
What am I doing wrong? 
 ElasticSearch version-1.4
Logstash version - 1.5 (initially tried also with 1.4)
 OS - CentOs 6.5 
Java - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.1.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14)

Comment: Does anything at all appear in your logstash.stdout file? Are there any errors or warnings in logstash.log or logstash.err ?

Comment: to better debug i am running logstash in bash with the command bash logstash -f my.config. The config file contains the upper configuration... I only get "Logstash startup completed" in the console - no error after which I do not receive any debug output (which I should I suppose)... Nothing in the .stdout file or .err.

Comment: Try including -l /your-logfile.log to get some logs coming from LS which may help you find the issue

Comment: the log file (specified as you mentioned) is created but remains empty. It is like the udp messages never reach the target port although tcpdump says 13:33:26.821332 IP [someip].64697 > [localip].5960: UDP, length 180. And according to netstat i have the port up once i start logstash 
udp   0     0 :::5960    :::*   28199/java

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you miss route to the sender. If this is the case what happen is:

1. You receive packet that was sent to your logstash IP/port.
2. You see it in tcpdump, since it's network layer.
3. Then kernel tries to reach sender (even for UDP).
4. If there is no route it fails, and hence dropping UDP packet and you don't see it on app level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check logstash log to see what host it opens port on. Default is 0.0.0.0. Which will not be reached. Add "host" parameter in udp definition.
2. Use port check tool ( like [qryport](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738095(v=ws.10).aspx) on Windows) to check whether port is actually listened.